# Why does spying on an instance using mockito doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am mocking a service layer and stubbing one of the method but doReturn doesnt return the mocked value. Bellow is my code, what i am doing wrong

```
 public class Service
 {
   @Autowired
    Dao dao;
   ....
   public int doSomething(){
      return 2;
   }
 }

@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class Test{

   @Autowired
   Service instanceOfService;

  @Test
  public void testMethod(){

   Service mockedService = Mockito.spy(instanceOfService)
   Mockito.doReturn(4).when(mockedService).doSomething();
   Assert.assertEquals(4, mockedService.doSomething());

    }
}
```

the assert fails here saying expected is <4> but was <2>

if i change the doReturn to this

```
Mockito.doReturn(4).when(mockedService.doSomething()).
```

then it throws this exception:

`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
  doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();`

and also if I change it to

`Mockito.when(mockedService.doSomething()).thenReturn(4);`

it throws this error:

`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: try: `Mockito.doReturn(4).when(mockedService.doSomething())` (parentheses are important & misleading here/not throwing compilation error) (`when().then..()` resp. `when(...).do...` is more convenient/readable order:)

Comment: ..and if you `@Autowire`/test your service, you probably want to/should mock the dao! (easiest with `@MockBean private Dao dao;` ...in your test, this creates a mock of the dao, which is connected to your (real) service)

Comment: ..and if it is `@IntegrationTest` (this seems to be spring-boot  < 2), then you probably don't want to mock anything/as few as possible.. :)

Comment: Mockito.doReturn(4).when(mockedService.doSomething()) didnt work for me. its throwing an error

Comment: @HabeGuema Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message you get.

Comment: @HabeGuema When you use your original unit test from your question, what is the error message you get or what is the problem you have? The mock setup looks fine, but there might be some issues with how the unit test is executed.

Comment: @Progman, the problem i am having is that the assert is failing . when i do mockedService.doSomething(). i am getting the result from the real method instead of the mocked result 4

Comment: @HabeGuema Does it work when you run your unit test not via spring but instead via junit directly? (Obviously you have to create a `Service` object by yourself then).

Comment: @Progman yes it does! so why is it not working for me when i run it via spring